# How to check if UICollectionViewCell subclass conforms to protocol

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UICollectionViewCell that conforms to the class protocol `VideoProtocol`:

```
class VideoCell : UICollectionViewCell, VideoProtocol {

}
```

I am trying to get an array of my visible `UICollectionViewCells` and filter them so that I only get an array of the ones that conform to `VideoProtocol`:

```
for cell in collectionView.visibleCells {
    //Do something here to check conformity
}
```

How do I do that? I want to make sure they have the properties of a `UICollectionViewCell` and `VideoProtocol`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let videoCells = collectionView.visibleCells.compactMap {
    $0 as? (UICollectionViewCell & VideoProtocol)
}
```

Note: Use `flatMap` instead of `compactMap`if you're using Swift <4.1

This little snipped should define `videoCells` as an array of `UICollectionViewCell`s that conform to `VideoProtocol`. If you do not need to access anything outside of what `VideoProtocol` defines, you can remove the `UICollectionViewCell` from the `as?` cast and just write `as? VideoProtocol` instead.

If you don't need either, and just want to check if the cells conform to the protocol without accessing anything defined in the protocol, you can do that easily by doing

```
let videoCells = collectionView.visibleCells.filter { $0 is VideoProtocol }
```

You can then use that like:

```
for cell in videoCells {
    // Do stuff with cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking for protocol conformance during each for loop;
*where `collectionView.visibleCells` is an array of `UICollectionViewCell`s.*

```swift
for case let cell as VideoProtocol in collectionView.visibleCells {
   // do something with cell
   // cell is type VideoProtocol
}
```

You're also be able to use the where clause during the for loop but that doesn't type cast the variable which means when you access the variable from within the for loop, you won't be accessing APIs from the protocol.

```swift
for cell in collectionView.visibleCells where cell is VideoProtocol {
   // do something with cell
   // cell is type UICollectionViewCell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for cell in collectionView.visibleCells 
{
    if let videoCell = cell as? VideoProtocol
    {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```